# Oracle Date Aggregating

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table in Oracle that has the daily sum of values.

My goal is to have this table display the monthly sum of values instead of daily.

I have this completed by using this query:

```
select to_char(dateid, 'YYYY-MM') as thedate, count(*)
from picture_table
group by to_char(dateid, 'YYYY-MM')
order by 1, 2
```

The issue here is that I have to transfer this oracle table to a table in MySQL. Since MySQL's DATE data structure is forced to be in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD', I am thinking I must append all my months to be 'YYYY-MM-01' so that "01" stands for the entire sum of the month.

Is it possible to do an oracle query to append a -01 to all my dates so they can be pipelined to MySQL table correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do that with a simple concat:

```
select to_char(dateid, 'YYYY-MM')||'-01' as thedate, count(*)
from picture_table
group by to_char(dateid, 'YYYY-MM')
order by 1, 2
```

However, why is the mysql table using a date field?  It could just have a varchar() column, to accept the "yyyy-mm" format?

Comment: I actually am using R to do some graphing with the data in MySQL and it's easier to graph when the values are in DATE format so that the X-axis can properly organize. I tried it with VARCHAR and R cannot organize the X-axis descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

It would generally make more sense (and be more efficient) to use the `TRUNC` function to truncate the date to the first of the month.  The resulting value will be of type `DATE`.

```
SELECT trunc(dateid, 'MM' ) thedate, count(*)
  FROM picture_table
 GROUP BY trunc(dateid, 'MM')
 ORDER BY 1, 2
```

It is not obvious what you mean by "pipeliend to MySQL" in your question.  I assume that whatever you are using to move data from Oracle to MySQL will be able to correctly handle mapping an Oracle `DATE` to a MySQL `DATE` or `DATETIME`.  It would seem very unusual if you had to convert the date in Oracle to a string in a particular format just to have MySQL perform an implicit conversion of that string back to a `DATE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can format the date just the same in MySQL, you only need a different function:

```
select date_format(dateid, '%Y-%m') as thedate, count(*)
from picture_table
group by date_format(dateid, '%Y-%m')
order by 1, 2
```

Example is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af6bd/2

Description of the date_format() function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format